# Brute forcing crypt() if salt and password hash are known?

Tags: c, linux, password-encryption, brute-force, crypt

Playing through some wargames and was curious if this was possible (they probably want you to solve it in a different way, but still).

There's a `.c` file with a function that has code that looks something like this:

```
char buffer[20];
scanf("%s", buffer);
char* hash = crypt(buffer, "$6$")
char* password = "$6$123456abcdef" #long string 
if (strcmp(password, hash) == 0) supersecretfunction();
```

Is there a way to brute force this considering the salt and hashed password are known already?

Comment: Depends on the encryption. To brute force you need to be able to compare an encrypted plain text to the ciphertext (i.e. you need to be able to reproduce the entire encryption method. Seeing as you have this function and you know the salt, I'd say you'd be able to. It all comes down to the key length of  the encryption. Modern encryption methods are computationally to difficult to use in a brute force. So find out how many possible ciphers you need to check and see how long it will take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike the original DES-based crypt() algorithm used in older Unix variants, which could be brute forced with relatively modest modern resources, newer Unices including most GNU/Linux flavours use an extended encrypted password specification. You can recognize this if the encrypted password (or salt) start with "$id$" where "id" is an algorithm identifier, see the table below.

"$6$" indicates that SHA-512 is used for the encryption (well, hashing actually). After the second '$' comes the salt, another '$' and the SHA-512 of the password.

The SHA-512 algorithm used is decribed in detail here: https://github.com/dchest/historic-password-hashes/blob/master/glibc-sha-crypt.txt

This algorithm involves, by default, 5000 rounds of SHA-512 for encrypting a single password. Doing a brute force attack would be computationally infeasible for even moderate length/complexity passwords. A dictionary based attack would be feasible but still time consuming for shorter, less complex passwords.

For the format of the password field, see the above linked article or for a summary see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html, quoted in part below:

> ```
>    If salt is a character string starting with the characters "$id$"
>    followed by a string terminated by "$":
>
>           $id$salt$encrypted
>
>    then instead of using the DES machine, id identifies the encryption
>    method used and this then determines how the rest of the password
>    string is interpreted.  The following values of id are supported:
>
>           ID  | Method
>           ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>           1   | MD5
>           2a  | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some
>               | Linux distributions)
>           5   | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
>           6   | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)
>
>    So $5$salt$encrypted is an SHA-256 encoded password and
>    $6$salt$encrypted is an SHA-512 encoded one.
>
>    "salt" stands for the up to 16 characters following "$id$" in the
>    salt.  The encrypted part of the password string is the actual
>    computed password.  The size of this string is fixed:
>
>    MD5     | 22 characters
>    SHA-256 | 43 characters
>    SHA-512 | 86 characters
>
>    The characters in "salt" and "encrypted" are drawn from the set
>    [a-zA-Z0-9./].  In the MD5 and SHA implementations the entire key is
>    significant (instead of only the first 8 bytes in DES).
> ```

Edit: This article may also be of interest: https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/hh-4.html